# GIF image is not working in .net MAUI application

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I would like to display some gif animation images in my application.
The library I used to do it with Xamarin.Forms was Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms. Now that we are migrating our application to .net MAUI, I see that the MAUI document says that it supports GIF files. I tried a sample, but it did not work.

I have seen a gif related bug and workaround in the following link, and I also tried it, but for me the gif animation is still not working.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5034

My code is on github, public repository.

https://github.com/rynjas/GifMauiSample

I would appreciate it if you could help me with this issue.

The steps to reproduce the issue are as follows:

1. Create a sample .NET MAUI project
2. Added a gif image to the Resources/images directory (giphy.gif)
3. Set the Build action of the gif image properties to MauiImage
4. Add an image component to the MainPage.xml, as follows
   Run the application, only the first frame of the GIF appears, no animation occurs.

```
    <Image Source="giphy.gif" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

5. I followed the workaround in the following ticket, so I added these steps to GIFMAUISample/GIFMAUISample.csproj
   https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5034

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\*.gif" Resize="False" />
```

The issue is still not resolved.

Comment: Its good that you gave a link to github with complete code. HOWEVER, Please add to the question the most relevant code text. StackOverflow is a long-term repository of useful info; links tend to break over time, so questions and answers must be complete even if links break.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The relevant code has been added to the issue.
Thank you for your time and reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the official documents by default when the gif image is loaded, by default it will not be played, Because `IsAnimationPlaying` property is set to `false`.

So, the gif image will not be played until you set `IsAnimationPlaying` to `true`.

**Here is a tested/working example:**

```xml
<Image Source="giphy.gif"
       HeightRequest="200" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" 
       IsAnimationPlaying="True" />
```

**important alert is written in the docs:**

While the animated GIF support in .NET MAUI includes the ability to download files, it does not support caching or streaming animated GIFs.

**Also be aware for android** that if it does not play in hot reload set `IsAnimationPlaying` to `false` and then set it back to `true`, while you are in hot reload mode and it should work fine

**iOS and Mac** are still facing some issues so you can keep track through:
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/866)

Microsoft docs: [.NET MAUI gif images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-animated-gifs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Good catch, you are correct.

Yes, when connected to hotreload on the Android platform, the animation does not work. 
If you set IsAnimationPlaying to false and then back to true, while in hot reload mode, it should work.

Besides the hot reload issue, Android is working fine, but iOS and macOS are still not working.

Comment: Is it working in iOS/macOS for you?

Comment: Actually there is a GitHub issue regarding this as you can see in the [Animated GIF files do not play on iOS/macOS](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/866)

Comment: We will keep this issue open until MAUI's ticket has been closed. The gif is having issue in MAUI, so this will help for others to know.

Comment: Agreed. Also, note that I've updated the question to have all links to the issue and docs. Please mark it as a correct answer so other people could participate and learn.

Answer (score 2):

Below is working code for me: it working with hot reload connect

```
<Image Source="giphy.gif"
       x:Name="imgLoader"
       HeightRequest="200" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" 
       IsAnimationPlaying="False" />

protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();
  await Task.Delay(100);
  imgLoader.IsAnimationPlaying = true;
}
```

[Git hub link](https://github.com/umeshkamble/GifAnimation)

Comment: Funny enough, in MAUI delaying 100 ms works. In Xamarin Forms, there was no need to toggle IsAnimationPlaying from false to true. MAUI still needs some work.

Comment: Does it work on iOS for you? It's not my case :/

Comment: for iOS please check this link https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/866#issuecomment-1515627910

Comment: I have updated sample for iOS

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to have **an animated gif both on IOS and Android** you can use an image (look above post from @Umesh Kamble) for Android which is working fine and a **webview as a workaround for IOS**.

At page initialization, you will hide the webview for android, and the non working animated image for ios.

Your page xaml will look like:

```
        <Image x:Name="imageLogo"
                Source="giphy.gif" IsAnimationPlaying="False"
                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120"/>
        
        <WebView x:Name="webLogo"
                 VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">

            <WebView.Source>
                <HtmlWebViewSource>
                    <HtmlWebViewSource.Html>
                        <![CDATA[
                        <HTML>
                        <BODY>
                        <img src="giphy.gif" style="width:80%"/>
                        </BODY>
                        </HTML>
                        ]]>
                    </HtmlWebViewSource.Html>
                </HtmlWebViewSource>
            </WebView.Source>
        </WebView>
```

and the xaml code behind will look like:

```
public MyPage()
{
#if ANDROID
        webLogo.IsVisible = false;
        imageLogo.IsVisible = true;
#else
        webLogo.IsVisible = true;
        imageLogo.IsVisible = false;
#endif
}

protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();
  await Task.Delay(100);
  imageLogo.IsAnimationPlaying = true;
}
```

Comment: I expanded on this concept and put a sample together here: https://github.com/billreiss/MauiGifWebView

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by simply doing this

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await Task.Delay(100);
    BreatheImageLoader.IsAnimationPlaying = false;
    await Task.Delay(100);
    BreatheImageLoader.IsAnimationPlaying = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image tag inside a UserControl (Doesn't have an OnAppearing  virtual method)
You can do this instead...

```
<Image SizeChanged="Image_SizeChanged"/>

...

private void Image_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var image = (Image)sender;
    image.IsAnimationPlaying = false;
    image.IsAnimationPlaying = true;
}
```