# Net Maui animated background

Tags: c#, .net, background, maui, .net-maui

I have a gif animation that i want to use as background for my ContentPage.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"
             BackgroundImageSource="background.gif">
```

I tried it this way but only the first frame is shown as static image.

Does anyone know how to set an animated background on Net Maui?

PS: This animation is from LottieFiles so i have the .gif and the .json file if I need that.

Comment: Look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72780267/gif-image-is-not-working-in-net-maui-application)

Comment: This example is only for an image. I mean the gif as background

Answer (score 0):

you can install  " SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui " plugin fron nuget package
and add the code in MauiProgram add "UseSkiaSharp"

```
  builder.UseMauiApp<App>().ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
           fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
           fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
       
        }).UseSkiaSharp();
```

in mainpage add grid
in grid you can add this code

```
<Grid >    
<skia:SKLottieView`
Source="an_back.gif"
RepeatCount="-1"
IsAnimationEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Doest it really work for a gif? I've installed the plugin: it's working for a json lottie file, but still not for a gif...